# SAP Hybris inStockFlag facet with just one option

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I want to use `inStockFlag` facet with only one option checked. I've added it - it's extended from `ProductInStockFlagValueProvider`. It shows on the page, but it shows with both options `TRUE` and `FALSE`:

[image]

I only need one option and it is "In Stock" checked or not checked to filter products only InStock or all products:

[image]

I've tried to add custom `valueDisplayNameProvider` for this facet and return empty string in case of `FALSE`, but it's still displaying both options (just one is with empty string). I'm using SAP Hybris v1811.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can write a custom value provider to check if it has stock. If it has, you can provide the String "In Stock" as value.

And if it doesn't have stock, you can return an empty `Collection<FieldValue>` from the method `getFieldValues` instead of providing an empty string.